# Unable to display Azure AD Location details on PnP Search Results

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, pnp-search-webparts

I am trying to display the user's **location** via Azure AD profile in the Pnp Search Results, however it is always returning empty.

#### AD User Details

[image]
[image]

---

#### Managed properties in SharePoint Admin

[image]

---

#### SharePoint Search Query Tool results

I see that the 3 "Office" fields  are displaying correctly, hence I believe it implies the properties have been properly crawled.

[image]

---

#### PNP Search Results settings

##### Layout Slot Settings

[image]

##### Handlebars Expression in Field Settings.

All these fields will return nothing

```
{{slot item @root.slots.OfficeLocation}} {{slot item @root.slots.OfficeNumber}} {{slot item @root.slots.Office}}
```

Comment: Have you selected these properties in search result web part "Select Properties" drop down?

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela Right that seemed to work now. It wasn't available as one of the dropdown options so I thought I need not set it. This field does not appear in the "Search Filter" though. Any idea what could be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select managed properties under "`Select Properties`".

For refiners, you are not seeing this in the selection because those are not refinable properties

[image]

If you want to use it for refiner then you need to map your crawled properties to any `RefinableString` managed properties (as we can't create new managed properties with the "`Refine`" option to true in SharePoint Online)

[image]

You can map your crawled properties (e.g. People.Office, etc.) to existing RefinablableString managed properties. Make sure that you also select this RefinableString properties to "Select Properties" in search result web part.
and then wait for next crawl cycle (you can except three two to four hours generally) and then those properties will be available in Filter web part as well.

Comment: Thank you @Kalpesh!

Comment: I have defined RefinableString to People:Office and waited for almost 1 week for the crawl. There are some data showing up on the Filters already but it's not accurate. Is there a way to view the status of the crawl?

Comment: As per my knowledge there is no way to check this status.